# Creation Of App Bundle For Instant App Module Is Not Possible

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have set up an app as an instant app based on this guides:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6
and https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/feature-plugin

So I have now 2 modules (installed & instant).
If I try to create an app bundle, then I'm not able to select the instant module, because the module selection is disabled in my case.

[image: a]

Running of the instant app is working as expected.

**Is it even possible to create an app bundle from an instant app module?**

**If yes, then what could be the problem?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your installed and instant app are all contained in that one bundle.

Then just upload that bundle into one of your Instant tracks.  (*note!! it must be one of your Instant tracks, not the regular app tracks*)

Yes, while that first statement is **not super** clear, this is how it is.

If you need some extra guidance on how to upload/publish your bundles, see bits at:

- [Deliver apps and features on demand with the Android App Bundle](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9006925)
- [instant-enabled-app-bundle#publish](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#publish)
- [Upload your app bundle to the Play Console](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle)
- [Build and deploy Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/#build)

Also, if you are also publishing your installed app from the same bundle, then after uploading to to your instant track, you can go to the installed track and select "ADD FROM LIBRARY".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But if I try to upload this bundle to the internal instant app test section, then I'm getting the error message: "You must upload an instant-enabled Android App Bundle to an instant track." Even if I try this with the sample [app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/multi-feature-module) from Google. (only changing package name and version)

Comment: Oh, well, right, for an "Instant App-supported App Bundle", you have to configure a few things first, see https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#configure

Comment: Also see https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/aab-simple

Comment: I see, it looks like the code labs tutorial, which I have used as reference, is using a legacy model of how to create instant apps. A good explanation between the old and new model can be found in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9J2e5PYXNg) Android Dev Summit. 
Using the new model I'm now able to create a "Instant App-supported App Bundle".
Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Correct, that codelab was made before App Bundles were released. Now that App Bundles are out and integrated with Instant Apps, a few things have changed. Also note that in Android Studio 3.3+, a new project structure of Instant Apps will be recommended: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features