# Instant app disabled when building app bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

I have create a base module (feature) and two others application and instantApp. I've built the application module as an app bundle and posted it to the store, and now I would like to do the same for the instant app but it will only allow me to build the module as an apk.

[image]

The "Module" is disabled, it's fixed on the application module, it won't let me change it.

My problem is that i if I build an apk, it will have more than 10MB, and instant apps need to be less than 10MB ...

What should I do now ?

Comment: If you've already built and published your App Bundle, and if it was correctly instant-enabled, you don't need to rebuild/publish it. You can just go to your Instant App release track, `create release`, and select from `ADD FROM LIBRARY`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#publish

Comment: But ... then why do through all the trouble of creating separate a module for the instant app ?!?!?!!??!!

Comment: Oh ! In case the apk would have been less than 10MB ... that would have been the best approach, if not, then don't split it into modules but keep it as one and use the "update from library"

Comment: "separate a module for the instant app" ? It's simply to let Play know that it doesn't have to dl all the entire app at once, only the minimum needed to have a functional instant app.

Comment: Plase write it as an answer. Also ... i've done so and published under internal test track, but when i click on add from library it doesn't show up in the list. Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creation Of App Bundle For Instant App Module Is Not Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152235/creation-of-app-bundle-for-instant-app-module-is-not-possible)