# Loading instant app "from library" doesn't see the full app bundle

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps

I've uploaded an app bundle to the internal test track (under `App releases`, so this is the full app) and then I'm going to the `Android instant apps` section and also under `Internal test track` I'm hitting the `Add from library` button, but it won't show the latest version in the list so I can choose it and let it generate instant apps from the apks.

And yes, I've waited a whole day for the full app to be visible, so it's not a matter of it not being synched, it's something else and I can't figure out what.

[image]

**EDIT**

The full app bundle I've uploaded was generate from my code which I've mudularized. I have a base module (feature), an (application) one and an (instant app). The app bundle is of the (application) module. I really can't see the use of the instant app, now that I'm using the `Add from library` button, but ... meh, that's how I'm doing it.

Should I post the app to production or another enviroment like alpha or beta for it to work or .... ?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creation Of App Bundle For Instant App Module Is Not Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152235/creation-of-app-bundle-for-instant-app-module-is-not-possible)

Comment: for an "instant-enabled" app bundle, you have to upload it to an `Instant track` first.